# Snowflake : How to create a view on json file on external S3 stage

Tags: json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to create a view on json file which is placed on external S3 stage of snowflake.
Json file structure is :

[{
'key1':val1,
'key2':val2
},
{
'key1':val1,
'key2':val2
}] 
I want to query json file with above structure.How can i do this?

Note : I am able to create a view on json file with below structure using flatten function -
{"Data": {
'key1':val1,
'key2':val2
},
{
'key1':val1,
'key2':val2
}}

But now my json structure is different and i don't have "Data" node in my above json structure.

Comment: Your data from before is not valid JSON, making it hard to guess what you really want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get past size limitations, use STRIP_OUTER_ARRAY=TRUE in the file format, so each object lands in its own row.

For example, assuming @my_stage/data.json points to a file containing:

```
[{ "key1":"val1", "key2":"val2" }, { "key1":"val3", "key2":"val4" }]
```

We can create this file format and view:

```
create or replace file format my_format type=json strip_outer_array=true;

create or replace view v_my_view as
select $1 data
from @my_stage/data.json 
(file_format=>my_format) a;
```

With these results:

```
select * from v_my_view;

DATA:KEY1 | DATA:KEY2
----------+----------
"val1"    | "val2"   
"val3"    | "val4"
```

Or flatten further:

```
create or replace view v_my_view_flat as
select b.key, b.path, b.index, b.value
from @my_stage/data.json 
(file_format=>my_format) a, lateral flatten(input=>a.$1) b;
```

To get this output:

```
KEY  | PATH | INDEX | VALUE 
-----+------+-------+-------
key1 | key1 |  NULL | "val1"
key2 | key2 |  NULL | "val2"
key1 | key1 |  NULL | "val3"
key2 | key2 |  NULL | "val4"
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want the obvious:

```
WITH MY_TABLE AS
  (SELECT PARSE_JSON('[{ ''key1'':1, ''key2'':2 }, { ''key1'':3, ''key2'':4 }]') obj)
SELECT VALUE:key1 key1, VALUE:key2 key2 FROM MY_TABLE
CROSS JOIN LATERAL FLATTEN(INPUT => obj);
```

or maybe you want something completely different.  Hard to tell...

Answer (score 0):

A couple comments on approach of processing JSON in Snowflake (regardless of  the specific examples and querying need of the JSON data)
- In general, we see the most popular way that Snowflake customers use to process JSON is to ingest into the VARIANT data type in a Snowflake table and querying from the VARIANT column.  Ingesting JSON into VARIANT is easy and same approach like relational data (e.g. Specify the file format, then use COPY INTO)
- This generalized approach (best practice) has the benefits of performance as well as supporting querying from VARIANT data in all standard SQL operations (join, group by, filtering) just like relational data.